# How to configure to proxy pass https requests from Apache http server to Jboss eap5.1 app server using mod_proxy_http?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, apache2, mod-proxy

I need your help in setting up a mod_proxy to pass https request from Apache2.0 httpserver to Jboss-Eap-5.1 app server.

- Environment Details:-

1) App server (Jboss Eap 5.1)  is configured and running on an Oracle Linux VM through Oracle Virtualbox Manager. 
2) The Apache2.0 http server is configured and running on Windows 7 host machine. VM is referred from host using a static ip through a hostonly adapter. 
3) Self signed certificate is created and installed on the app server using "keygen"
4) App server is configured and listening on port 8843 for https and 8080 for http. This is tested by hitting the instance from the host browser through https channel via port 8843 and http via port 8080 and the site renders
5) Self signed SSL certificate is created and installed on the web server using "openssl" and it is configured and listening on port 443 for https and 80 for http.
6) I was able to set the proxy for http non-secure schemes

- Problem:-
  But when I try to set the proxy for https I see a 500 error on the browser. Below are my configuration details

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile C:\web.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\web.key
ProxyPass / https://vm:8843/
ProxyPassReverse / https://vm:8843/
ProxyTimeout 600

I think that the request is truncated at the webserver level and because of improper ssl  hand shake between the app server and web server servers 500 error back to the browser.

I'm a new in setting up mod_proxy.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Sincerely,
Pavan

Comment: Figured out...

Solution:- 
I needed to turn on the "SSLProxyEngine" .

Add 

SSLProxyEngine on to <VirtualHost *:443> tag

Comment: As you found a solution to your problem yourself, please post it as an answer, so this question will stop appearing to be open in SO.